# Android setVisibility issue with android 2.3.3

Tags: android, layout, view

Just a straight forward problem. I have a LinearLayout which has attribute in xml `android:visibility="invisible"`. In code I am using `layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);`. It works fine for android 2.2 i.e. getting visible but not working in android 2.3.3 i.e. not getting visible.

```
<LinearLayout
      android:id="@+id/menuLayout"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_gravity="bottom"
      android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
      android:background="#60000000"
      android:visibility="invisible">
      <Button 
          android:id="@+id/restartSamePlayer"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="Play Again"
          android:onClick="clearCanvas"
          />
      <Button 
          android:id="@+id/restartNewPlayer"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="New Player"
          android:onClick="findNewPlayer"
          />      
  </LinearLayout>

 menuLayout = (LinearLayout) activity.findViewById(R.id.menuLayout);
      if(menuLayout == null)
        System.out.println("Null");
      menuLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
      if(menuLayout.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)
        System.out.println("Visible");
```

in my log i can see visible but it is not getting visible in emulator having 2.3.3

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Could you please provide your layout and the code and context in which you change the visibility?

Comment: The code is executed in `onCreate`?

Comment: @WarrenFaith no in other method on some condition.As you can see in my question it is working for 2.2 but not for 2.3.3

Comment: Just a guess, but I would try to call `invalidate()` on the `menuLayout` and/or the parent. The way of UI drawing have had some basic changes done in the last few versions...

Comment: can you paste your complete code.i.e., oncreate method

Comment: @Agarwal nothing much in onCreate().It is wokring fine for 2.2.So no problem in code i think.for 2.3.3 it has some problem

Comment: @WarrenFaith if i will use invalidate(), then can i use it again ?

Comment: Where are you inflating your menuLayout? is it part of the xml which is set in the setContentView()?

Comment: invalidate is just a call that informs android to draw the layout again. It has nothing to do with "reusable" or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code

```
 android:visibility="gone"
```

Comment: i dont want to make it gone.i cant use it again if i will do so.

Comment: @AndroidKiller Sorry, but this is just wrong. You can "reuse" a layout even if it is `gone`. The difference between gone and invisible is, that gone doesn't take any place on the screen while invisible takes the place it should have (like a placeholder) but it is not visible.

Comment: @WarrenFaith If it is gone how can i use it ? if i will set it to visible,will it work ?

Comment: This is so easy to test on yourself... try it and you will see it should work :)

Comment: It worked.I was stupid mind.Sorry guys.Thanks Narendra and WarrenFaith

Answer (score 0):

```
menuLayout = (LinearLayout) activity.findViewById(R.id.menuLayout);
```

change it to

```
menuLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.menuLayout);
```

now try it

Comment: guess into the blue. Where did you saw that `activity` is not the same like `this`?

Comment: @Agarwal i am accessing this outside my main activty and i am passing my Activty vairable to that class and "activity" is that variable.So i cant access directly as you are saying.

Comment: it must be the problem in parent layout not here can we have the parent XML file